# How to pause timer in windows phone?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone

In this code after starting timer again it starts from the current value instead of the vale it stopped. How to pause this timer?

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _rnd = new Random();
    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
    _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var time = DateTime.Now - _startTime;
    txtTime.Text = string.Format(Const.TimeFormat, time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
}

public void NewGame()
{
    _moves = 0;
    txtMoves.Text = "0";
    txtTime.Text = Const.DefaultTimeValue;
    Scrambles();
    while (!CheckIfSolvable())
    {
      Scrambles();
    }

    _startTime = DateTime.Now;
    _timer.Start();

    //GridScrambling.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void Pause_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page4.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    _timer.Stop();
}

private void Play_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
    _timer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.stop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that the `Stop` method only changes the `IsEnabled` property and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.isenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that this property only prevents the `Tick` event to be raised, I don't think that there is a method to simply 'pause' the timer. The best way is to reinitialize the timer each time you have "paused" it, if you really want it to start clean again.

But I do not think that this is you real problem. When you pause your game the timer stops working. When you continue it the timer starts working again. When you now try the calculate the time from THIS moment till the start time, then you make a big mistake: you have to ignore the paused time. Because when you play the game 2s, then pause it for 10s and then continue the game, the timer shows 12s, instead of 2s, doesn't it? Maybe you should store the paused times in a variable and substract that from the real game time.

Comment: How can i store the paused value and how to substract that from the real game time? please explain me by code

Comment: @Viju009 You can create one public variable named `pausedTime` store the paused time, and one named `pausedStartingTime` in which you store the time when the pause was started. When your `Pause_Click` method is called you simply set the `pausedStartingTime` to the current time. In the resume game method you simply have to substract the `pausedStartinTime` from the current time and you get your paused time. You now add this value to the `pausedTime` in order to store multiple pauses. In you `TimerTick` you now have to calculate the `time` someway like this
`DateTime.Now-_startTime-pausedTime;`

Comment: How can I get the current time value of my timer? for assinging it to pausedTime

Comment: just use `DateTime.Now` and then calculate the difference as I told you above. @Viju009

Comment: when i write DateTime.Now-_startTime-pausedTime it shows me error that operator '-' can't be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'System.DateTime'.

Comment: @Viju009 Then use this `var time = DateTime.Now - _startTime - new TimeSpan(pausedTime.Ticks);`

Comment: When i use this expression it gives me time something like -17:-18:-56